# vba code for changing query xls source prompt

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I was searching for a simple vba code that open the prompt for change source for query that is xls sheet. I have a lot of query steps that i need to do every time that source is changing. 
So basically i would like to have macro that does this manual steps for a certain query name (i have a number of them in a workbook):
in the query edit mode, click the source change button:[source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyKhO.png)

macro should open the prompt so that i can manually pick the xls file:[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBqEo.png)

also, the data can be in a sheet that have different name than previously, so i have to also navigate to proper sheet/table so that "navigation" prompt would be also nice to open so i can manually choose:
[button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYGUI.png)
[nagivation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmuW7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Create a cell in excel workbook that contains the full path of desired filename like **c:\temp\directory\subdirectory\filename.xlsx** and give that cell a range name, here "TheFilename" in my example

Create a cell in excel workbook that contains name of desired input tab on filename like **Sheet1** and give that cell a range name, here "TheSheet" in my example

Use those range names in powerquery as variables using syntax

```
Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="rangeName"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]
```

as in this example

```
let
TheFilename = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TheFilename"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
TheSheet= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TheSheet"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(TheFilename), null, true),
Data = Source{[Item=TheSheet,Kind="Sheet"]}[Data]
in Data
```

Comment: Might be worth adding `=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",$A$1))-1),"[","")` to the cell which you want to contain the file name - will return the path & name of the file.

Comment: Your file location might start 'https' in which case you'll need to use `Web.Contents` rather than `File.Contents` - you could use a `if then else` block to check the first characters of the file path and use the correct source method depending on that.