# PowerQuery in Excel Worksheet is broken when the Worksheet is copied, but parameters aren't helping

Tags: excel, parameters, powerquery

In my Excel workbook I have "Worksheet_1" which contains "Table_1" from which I made "Query_1" and placed it's output on the same worksheet. Nice and tidy.
If I copy this worksheet using the standard "Move/Copy" command and smartly rename my new copies as "Worksheet_2", "Table_2", and "Query_2". All is fine except that **"Query_2" is still referencing "Table_1"**...

Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_1"]}[Content]

...but I need it to reference "Table_2".

*The current workaround is to instruct users how to dive into the M code and change this line manually*, but is there a better way?

A parameterized query seems logical but since the parameter must itself reference a table which must live on the original worksheet (to get the table name), that parameter itself references the original "Worksheet_1" and it's the same problem as before.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60986680/vba-code-for-changing-query-xls-source-prompt/60991048#60991048

Comment: Thanks - This might work if I replace all the separate queries with a single one and drive the input table manually, say through a user-selected dropdown list. Since all my defined names are scoped to the worksheet (not the workbook), I'm spoiled and I think copying worksheets should be just as easy in the powerquery world and all variables just update by themselves, but it doesn't appear to be the case. Either way I'm thinking this needs VBA. Thanks again.